# Why does Spring Boot ignore my CustomErrorController?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, error-handling

I have a custom ErrorController like this:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error42")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
      
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        System.err.println(status);

        if (Objects.isNull(status)) return "error";

        int statusCode = Integer.parseInt(status.toString());
        String view = switch (statusCode) {
            case 403 -> "errors/403";
            case 404 -> "errors/404";
            case 500 -> "errors/500";
            default -> "error";
        };

        return view;
    }
}
```

And then I've set the server.error.path property like this:

```
server.error.path=/error42
```

So far, so good. Everything works fine. All the errors go through my CustomErrorController.

But when I set the error path to `server.error.path=/error` - and of course I change the request mapping annotation to `@RequestMapping("/error")` - this won't work anymore.

Spring Boot now completely ignores my CustomErrorController. I know, I've set the path to the one Spring Boot usually defines as standard, but is there no way to override this?

Many thanks for any information clearing up this weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, and it was solely my own fault. Since especially at the beginning of a Spring Boot career, the setting options quickly become overhelming, and one can lose sight of one or the other adjustment made, I would still like to leave this question and answer it myself.

The culprit was a self-configured view that i did weeks ago and completely lost track of:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /* FYI: will map URIs to views without the need of a Controller */
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login")
                .setViewName("/login");

        registry.addViewController("/error")  // <--- Take this out !!!
                .setViewName("/error");

        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```

May this help others facing the same mystery, why once again nothing runs quite as desired...